# Why gradient descent blows up almost every time?

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I tried writing the GD algorithm from scratch (actually I borrowed the code from one Git repo which I
am gonna credit soon). The thing is it blows up (get `+Inf or -Inf) and I cannot see where the problem lies. Tried changing alpha to a really small value, it still didn't work out (got wrong values), though it didn't blow up.

Here is the code I used:

```
# features
x <- with(
  data = mtcars,
  cbind(hp, disp)
)
# target var
y <- mtcars$mpg
N <- length(y)

# optimal values with in-built lm function
res <- lm(y~x)

# define cost function to minimize
cost <- function(X, y, theta){
  sum((X %*% theta - y)^2)/N
}

# training params
alpha = 0.00005
n_max <- 1000

# log the changes
cost_history <- double(n_max)
theta_histoty <- vector("list", n_max)

# initialize the coeffs
theta <- matrix(rep(0, ncol(x) + 1), ncol = 1)
rownames(theta) <- c("(Intercept)", "hp", "disp")

# add ones to the feature matrix
X <- cbind(1, x)

# train
for(i in seq_len(n_max)){
  error <- (X %*% theta - y)
  delta <- t(X) %*% error / N
  theta <- theta - alpha*delta
  cost_history[[i]] <- cost(X, y, theta)
  theta_histoty[[i]] <- theta
}

# check
theta;coef(res)
```

Comment: It is a converging problem. Set the `N <- ncol(X)+1` , `alpha <- 0.000002`  and `n_max <- 15*10^5` . You will get the result. By the way, I found this guys by trial. There may exist some more efficient hyperparameter setting. It must be actually! 1.5 million iteration is just too much for this kind of problem! I just wanted to show you that it stems from your hyperparameters...

Comment: This is more of a optimization problem than a programming question

Comment: Please be more specific than "blows up"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your problem is particularly poorly suited to gradient descent.  It's hard to visualize the cost function, but contours of it are ellipses, with drastically different axis lengths.  Unless you take tiny steps (`alpha = 1e-5` worked for me), most steps will jump right across the valley and you get a worse value.  If you do take tiny steps, then it takes a really long time to converge, because you're taking tiny steps.  With `alpha = 1e-5` and `n_max = 1e6` you can see things are converging, but it's still a long way from the optimal value.

You can speed it up a lot by standardizing the predictors.  Using

```
x <- with(
  data = mtcars,
  cbind(scale(hp), scale(disp))
)
```

will make it really fast with `alpha = 1`.  The `scale()` function subtracts the mean and divides by the standard deviation.